# Compiler optimizations when reading a file

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, fread

I'm starting to write a c++ program that is supposed to read a large binary file (several gigabytes). As a start, my program just does `fread()` inside a loop to read into an array of doubles:

```
double *arr = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ARRSIZE);
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
int num_read;
do {
    num_read = fread(arr, sizeof(double), ARRSIZE, fp);
} while (num_read > 0);
free(arr);
```

I want to see the throughput of my program, but I find that I can read two gigabytes in about half a second. Are there any compiler optimizations that may have ignored the `fread()` calls if I'm not doing anything with the data?

If there are, how can I be sure I'm seeing the actual maximum throughput of my program?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure the throughput of your program?

Comment: It would be a compiler bug if a compiler were to omit a call to fread. The rules of C++ require all calls to standard library functions to be performed in the order specified by the program.

Comment: Your OS is probably caching the file. Flush the file cache before doing any benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Oswald: I just measure the time my program runs in. All I need to know is how much time I need to read 2 gigs.